# Hosting spacy models using sagemaker with endpoint

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I'm new to sagemaker, My requirement is i have spacy model(where there is no training required),Now i want to deploy the model using sagemaker with endpoint, so that i can use that endpoint in my project. I'm following this [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-run-spacy-on-aws-sagemaker-custom-containers-quick-and-easy-884a6898ed48), but i didn't figure out on how to use this model as an endpoint. Can someone help me in getting this done.